# Access command to record new records from listbox if not existing already

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working with MS Access 2013 at my work and have been asked to set up a database that can keep track of employee training. Currently I have a form that they can choose the department and which training they are doing, along with the current date. Based on the department they are able to choose from a listbox the employees that are present for that training session.

I have been able to use an update query to update the current records of the employees training *Date Completed* using this code

```vb
Private Sub cmdDocument_Click()
    Dim Q As QueryDef, DB As Database
    Dim Criteria As Variant
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim Itm As Variant

    Set ctl = Me![lstEmployeeNames]

    For Each Itm In ctl.ItemsSelected
        If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
            Criteria = Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)
        Else
            Criteria = Criteria & "," & Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)
        End If
    Next Itm

    If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
        Itm = MsgBox("You must select Employee Name(s) in the List!", 0, _
                     "No Selection Made")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("qRecord_CleanUp")
    Q.SQL = "UPDATE tblTraining Set [Date Completed] = " _ 
            & " Forms![frmTraining]![sfrmTraining].Form![txtDate] " _
            & " WHERE (((tblTraining.EmployeeID) IN (" & Criteria & "))" _
            & " AND ((tblTraining.TrainingID)=" _
            & "      Forms![frmTraining]![sfrmTraining].Form![cboTraining]));"
    Q.Close

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qRecord_CleanUp"

End Sub
```

However the issue is that I can't add new records. I can update current records if the employee already has done the training in the past, but if it is the employees first training I haven't been able to figure out how to add a new record for that individual employee. I have tried to come up with an append query to accomplish this but haven't been able to get it to work quite right with the listbox of employees (bound to *EmployeeID*).

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with a recordset. Read into them here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197799.aspx

The following code is an example, you will need to do a little refining:

```
Private Sub cmdDocument_Click()
Dim Q As QueryDef, DB As Database
Dim Criteria As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
Dim Itm As Variant
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set ctl = Me![lstEmployeeNames]
'Set the recordset, and move last to load the entire set
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTraining")
rs.MoveLast
rs.Edit
For Each Itm In ctl.ItemsSelected
    'Look for the current employee
    rs.FindFirst "EmployeeID = &Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)"
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
            Criteria = Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)
        Else
            Criteria = Criteria & "," & Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)
        End If
    Else
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("EmployeeID") = ctl.ItemData(Itm)
        rs.Fields("Date Completed") = txtDate
        rs.Fields("TrainingID") = cboTraining
        rs.Update
    End If
Next Itm
If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
    Itm = MsgBox("You must select Employee Name(s) in the List!", 0, "No Selection Made")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set DB = CurrentDb()
Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("qRecord_CleanUp")
Q.SQL = "Update tblTraining Set [Date Completed] = Forms![frmTraining]![sfrmTraining].Form![txtDate]  WHERE (((tblTraining.EmployeeID) IN (" & Criteria & ")) AND ((tblTraining.TrainingID)=Forms![frmTraining]![sfrmTraining].Form![cboTraining]));"
Q.Close

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qRecord_CleanUp"

End Sub
```

I'm using your existing code for found records, it would be better (and not that hard) to also use a recordset for them. Also, your "if noone is selected" code will now trigger sometimes when it's not needed.

Comment: Thank You, I don't know why I didn't think of putting the record set to find match in an If statement. However, just looking for the EmployeeID to match will come up with all the trainings that each employee does (depending on department an employee could have to do 25-45 different trainings), which is why in the sql I had I compared it to also the TrainingID, I assume I can just add that to the FindFirst with an AND statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a database design issue and not programming one. You should not need any append or update queries. An MS Access form should handle that data functionality, namely edit/add/delete actions through GUI.

Consider the following setup:

1. Add a new join table like *EmployeeTrainings* with foreign key IDs for related tables,  *Employees* and *Trainings* that maintains a one-to-many relationship with both of them. Also add training session level details like *DateCompleted* in this table.
2. Create a single or multiple-item form whose recordsource is this new table.
3. Add listboxes or comboboxes on form whose control sources are *EmployeeID* and *TrainingID*.

From there, on this form the user can navigate to a new or existing record, selecting the needed *Employee* and *Training* from listboxes. If needing to update, search or navigate to that record and edit on form. If needing to add, go to empty row (for continuous form) or page (for single form) and begin entering needed data. This way you also maintain a history of trainings and not continuously update the same employee rows. Querying of course is simply by joining tables on related IDs.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with for a while I got it work, this is the final code

```
Private Sub cmdDocument_Click()
Dim Q As QueryDef, DB As Database
Dim Criteria As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
Dim Itm As Variant
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set ctl = Me![lstEmployeeNames]

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTraining", dbOpenDynaset)
rs.MoveLast
rs.Edit
For Each Itm In ctl.ItemsSelected
    If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
        Criteria = Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)
    Else
        Criteria = Criteria & "," & Chr(32) & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(32)
    End If
    If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
        Itm = MsgBox("You must select Employee Name(s) in the List!", 0, "No Selection Made")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    rs.FindFirst "[EmployeeID] = " & ctl.ItemData(Itm) & " And [TrainingID] = " & Me![cboTraining]

        If Not rs.NoMatch Then
            Set DB = CurrentDb()
            Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("qRecord_CleanUp")
            Q.SQL = "Update tblTraining Set [Date Completed] = Forms![frmTraining]![sfrmTraining].Form![txtDate]  WHERE (((tblTraining.EmployeeID) IN (" & Criteria & ")) AND ((tblTraining.TrainingID)=Forms![frmTraining]![sfrmTraining].Form![cboTraining]));"
            Q.Close
        Else
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("EmployeeID") = ctl.ItemData(Itm)
            rs.Fields("Date Completed") = txtDate
            rs.Fields("TrainingID") = cboTraining
            rs.Fields("Department") = txtDepartment
            rs.Update
        End If
Next Itm

DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qRecord_CleanUp"

End Sub
```